# subquery with from subquery mysql unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, subquery

I have the following query

```
SELECT
a.*, count(
    (SELECT matches.id FROM (
        SELECT
            p.id,
            IF ( p.verdeelbaar = '1', MIN(s.minopp), SUM(s.minopp) ) AS min,
            SUM( s.maxopp ) AS max,
            samenstelling_type_id,
            samenstelling_type_absolute_parent(samenstelling_type_id) AS top_type
        FROM
            app_pand AS p
        LEFT JOIN
            app_samenstelling AS s
        ON
            p.id = s.pand_id
        WHERE
            s.samenstelling_beschikbaarheid_id NOT IN (12,13)
        AND
            s.actief = 1
        AND 
            IF(a.hk!='te huur/te koop',hk = a.hk,TRUE)
        GROUP BY
            pand_id, top_type
        HAVING
            CASE top_type
                WHEN @kantoor THEN
                    min < a.kantoor_max AND max > a.kantoor_min
                WHEN @magazijn THEN
                    min < a.magazijn_max AND max > a.magazijn_min
                WHEN @terrein THEN
                    min < a.terrein_max AND max > a.terrein_min
            END

        ) AS matches
    GROUP BY matches.id )
) AS m
FROM
app_aanvragen AS a
WHERE a.id = @aanvraag;
```

Whit this query I want to the calculate number of matches for one `aanvraag (the dutch word for a request)`.

The problem is that in the most inner query, the `FROM` from `matches` does not know about the `a` records `(a.hk, a.kantoor, a.magazijn..)`.

I know many solutions on this problem say that you must join both tables, and that way reach the `a`records, but I don't see how to join them, because they have no join condition.

Is this query possible in the first place, and if so, how should I do it? And if not, does anybody sees another solution for this problem?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: If there is no join between app_aanvragg and the sub-select app_pand, how does the count work? In other words, it seems there has to be some connection for it to be counted? It would probably be clearer if I spoke Dutch.

Comment: To explain what the query should do: I have a collection of buildings,  and a set of requests, and matching to the conditions in the request, the building must be selected. So if I have a request searching for an office with a min and a max surface, the count should give me how much buildings have an office with that surface.

Comment: In general, I think you'd want to turn this all into JOINs, and maybe use UNION to merge 3 different queries for each of the cases from the HAVING, but the max and min being generated values makes that tough.

Comment: I couldn't say for certain that there's not a query, but the easiest way forward would probably be to create a procedure to handle this. Calculate the min/max in one step. Then you could calculate the count, and then a straightforward select. I haven't thought it all the way through, but it would probably be sufficient to calculate the min-max and then JOIN the tables to do the data and count select together. Would that work?